# Why is the bottom of a vertical scroll bar being cut off in IE 11?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I am having an issue seen at the following stackblitz link where the bottom of my content and the bottom of the scroll bar that should allow you to view that content are being clipped off of the screen in IE11.

I've successfully gotten this working in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge but have had no luck figuring out this issue in IE11.

[Stackblitz Editor Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/inline-conditional-component)

[Stackblitz App Link](https://inline-conditional-component.stackblitz.io)

Edit 1:

Here is a Code Pen that reproduces the issue purely in HTML and CSS.

```
// Code snippet to make stack overflow happy.
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/amayer42/pen/MXXYJe)

Comment: You should post a real code snippet instead of trying to fake one.

Comment: If there was a code snippet to post, I'd probably post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `css`, for `html, body { }` overflow is set to `hidden`, which was causing the problem in `IE11`. Set it to `overflow: visible;` to make it work.

Final CSS will be like this:

```css
/* Add application styles & imports to this file! */
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';

html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And here's the `stackblitz` link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/inline-conditional-component-px4p6f?file=src/styles.css

Comment: That's awesome that does fix it.  I guess I don't really understand why that matters though.  I'm confused as to why that portion of the content is extending beyond the height of the page.  Thanks for finding it though!